# Getting frame rate from AVCaptureVideoDataOutput

Tags: iphone, avfoundation

I'm using `AVCaptureVideoDataOutput` to grab frames, process them, and then write them to a MOV file using `AVAssetWriter`.  I understand that to set the minimum frame rate for the data input, I need only write

`myDataOutput.minFrameDuration = someCMTime;`

How can I get the actual frame duration for a given cycle of

`- (void) captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput didOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection`

I need the actual duration so that I can input an accurate duration time for the asset writer.  I've been playing around with using `CMSampleBufferGetDuration(sampleBuffer)`, but with limited success.  Any idea how to get this value?

Here is my current captureOutput method implementation:

```
- (void) captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput didOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection 
{
    if([writerInput isReadyForMoreMediaData])
    {

        CVImageBufferRef imageBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer);

        if(imageBuffer){

            totalTime = CMTimeAdd(totalTime, CMSampleBufferGetDuration(sampleBuffer));


            if([adaptor appendPixelBuffer:imageBuffer withPresentationTime:totalTime]){
                NSLog(@"frame added");
                CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(imageBuffer,0);
            }else{
                NSLog(@"frame NOT added");
            }

        }else{
            NSLog(@"no buffer");
        }
    }else{
        NSLog(@"writerinput not ready");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end, the problem was that I was using `AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor`, which requires the user to set the presentation time.  Instead, I ended up just adding frames directly by calling `appendBuffer` on `AVAssetWriterInput`